# Monadic if - how it works?

Tags: haskell, monads

`ifM` is implemented as:

```
ifM p t f  = p >>= (\p' -> if p' then t else f)
```

And another function `while2` uses `ifM` like this,

```
while2 x y = ifM x (return ()) $ ifM y (return ()) $ while2 x y
```

My questions are:

- ifM takes three arguments. What are their types? (i understood it as, p - predicate function, t - true function block, f - false function block)
- In the usage of `ifM` inside `while2`, when does the argument 
  evaluation happen? Does the arguments coming after `$` get evaluated first and their values passed as arguments to `while2`
- What does `ifM` do that `if` cannot do?

Comment: `If` you want to find out the type, `then` load your code into GHCi!

Comment: what worked during compilation using ghc, didn't work with GHCi.. the code i am discussing is @ http://porg.es/blog/simple-socket-programming-with-haskell

Comment: `ifM` loaded fine: `ifM :: Monad m => m Bool -> m a -> m a -> m a`.

Comment: i see it, AJFarmar.. i tried to load the entire module as :l socket.hs.. that didn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's [type](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/extra-1.1/docs/Control-Monad-Extra.html#v:ifM) is:

```
ifM :: Monad m => m Bool -> m a -> m a -> m a
```

To see how it works, you can just test it in `ghci` and find out it's
   behaviour:

```
λ> ifM (return True) (print "true") (print "false")
"true"
λ> ifM (return False) (print "true") (print "false")
"false"
```

So based on the result of the first monadic boolean parameter, either one of the monadic expression is executed. It is different from the normal `if` in the way that it takes monadic values.

while2 has this type signature:

```
while2 :: Monad m => m Bool -> m Bool -> m ()
```

You can get an idea of how it works by seeing this example:

```
λ> while2 (print "hello" >> return True) (return True)
"hello"
λ> while2 (print "hello" >> return True) (print "bye" >> return True)
"hello"
λ> while2 (print "hello" >> return False) (print "bye" >> return True)
"hello"
"bye"
```

So in `while2` function, the first monadic value is executed. If it
   Sevaluates to `True`, then `return ()` is executed. If it's false,
   then `ifM y (return ()) $ while2 x y` is executed with the same
   rules of `ifM`. Now if `y` evaluates to `False`, then the `while2`
   is evaluated again in an recursive manner leading to infinite loop:

```
λ> while2 (print "hello" >> return False) (print "bye" >> return False)
"hello"
"bye"
"hello"
"bye"
"hello"
"bye"
"hello"
"bye"
C-c
```